# CSS - Space at top of website

Tags: css

I have a space at the top of my website and in my stylesheet I am using the `margin="0"` and it should work, but does not.

This is a wordpress theme website and I looked at my page source and found the style code below which I assume was generated by wordpress, but I cannot find it anywhere to edit it.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

Please explain how I can do this?

Comment: ask the theme developer if they have support

Comment: unfortunately it was a theme I had someone of fiverr complete which they did not and was a real mess and they are not responding took my payment and did not complete project

Comment: which explain how bad the code is ... in this case hire a better developer to fix the job

Comment: wish we could but where would I find this code have looked in every file

Comment: How many plugins you using? Try disabling them all.

Comment: We're not going to be able to tell you where in your file system a piece of code is stored. Use the facilities of your operating system to search for that text in the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare any styles directly to `body/html` tags,after `body` tag open one new `div` tag and close it before `body` tag close then you declare margin for that `div`,see the below example.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>

.container
 {
   margin-top: 32px;
 }
```